# calling a filter which is out of the scope of the current controller

Tags: angularjs

Ok, I have a controller named `LinesCtrl` which is displaying some data in the `body` of the `html`, and I have another controller named `MenuController` which is the controller for the `navbar`, in that `navbar` I have a search-bar(`input type=search`) which belongs to `LinesCtrl`

```
<nav class="navbar"
     ng-controller="MenuController"
     ng-show="displayLogout">

      <div class="navbar-form">
        <!--this is the input which must be attached to LinesCtrl-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="search"
                 ng-model="search"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="button">Account Figures</button>
          <button type="button">Log out</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

as you can see above there is an `input` within a `form-group`, that is the `input` which belongs to `LinesCtrl`, as I have it inside `MenuController` in the `html`, the `input`(filter) doesn't work at all, so, what are the options I have ?

someone recommend me to use `broadcast` or `emit`.

Let me paste my code for the controller that I want to communicate each other

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
  .controller('MenuController', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.displayLogout = false;
    AuthFactory.getCustomer().then(function(customer) {
      $scope.displayLogout = true;
    });
    $scope.$on('loginController:loggedIn', function() {
      $scope.displayLogout = true;
    });
    $scope.$on('loginController:loggedOut', function() {
      $scope.displayLogout = false;
    });

    $scope.logout = function() {
      AuthFactory.logout();
      AuthFactory.broadcastLogout();
      $scope.displayLogout = false;
    };
  });
```

that one is the controller which wraps the `navbar`, so once the user is logged out, the `navbar` just disappear. and that is OK, my issue is, that the `input` belongs to another controller so is not working once you try to look up for something.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
  .controller('LinesCtrl', function($scope) {

   ....

});
```

so how can I work here with an `emit` or a `broadcast` but using `$rootScope` ?

Comment: _input(filter) doesn't work at all_ means what exactly? And why is the question phrased _calling a filter_? What do you mean by that? Your HTML shows no `LinesCtrl` and how can an `input` belong to a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my own answer:

**menuController**

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
  .controller('MenuController', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.broadcastSearchBar = function() {
       $rootScope.$emit('menuController:searching', $scope.search);
    };
  });
```

**html**

```
          <input ng-change="broadcastSearchBar()"
                 type="search"
                 ng-model="search"/>
```

**linesCtrl**

```
$rootScope.$on('menuController:searching', function($event, searchArg) {
  $scope.search = searchArg;
});
```